# Change only one cell on tr hover

Tags: css, row, cell

I have 5 cells in each row.  I can change the background on all 5 cells with:

```
tr:hover {
   background: some_color;
}
```

But I want cell number 5 to be a different color.  Need answer using css, js, or jquery.

Comment: Thank you Hao Wu that does seem to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may specify the fifth cell using [`:nth-of-type` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

```css
tr:hover td:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: some_color;
}
```

```css
tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: salmon;
}

tbody tr:hover td:nth-of-type(5) {
  background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
      <th>Header 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1-1</td>
      <td>Cell 1-2</td>
      <td>Cell 1-3</td>
      <td>Cell 1-4</td>
      <td>Cell 1-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 2-1</td>
      <td>Cell 2-2</td>
      <td>Cell 2-3</td>
      <td>Cell 2-4</td>
      <td>Cell 2-5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 3-1</td>
      <td>Cell 3-2</td>
      <td>Cell 3-3</td>
      <td>Cell 3-4</td>
      <td>Cell 3-5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```